# Elasticsearch dotnet client error on aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest, aggregation

I am a newbie in elastic and we are using NEST (elasticsearch official dotnet driver) version 5.5, and it is working fine with query and filters, however I am facing an issue when it comes to aggregations.

sample app in my github available [here](https://github.com/milianoo/ElasticSearch-Dotnet-Core)

The requirement is to get distinct list of first names (as an example) in the available index (People) which contains list of Persons objects.

the object class is like this:

```
 public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<string> Skills { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Others { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, object> OthersObject { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to implement Terms Aggregation, and it is not working even on simple scenarios: [(docs available here)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/terms-aggregation-usage.html)

```
        var result = _client.Search<Person>(s => s
            .Size(0)
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms("firstnames", t => t.Field(f => f.FirstName))
            )
            .Query(q => q
                .MatchAll()
            )
        );
```

Once the query is executed, the result state is **invalid** and below error is available in debug information:

#### Error :

Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /people/person/_search
Audit trail of this API call:
 - BadResponse: Node: http://127.0.0.1:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.6674180
ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed"

Unfortunately, that's all I get as an error. any idea on how to proceed is welcome.

Comment: What does fiddler show? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html

Comment: I will enable fiddler and update the question, asap.